# Big text inside fixed size element

Tags: html, css

I want to create round +/- buttons. As of now I have tried using background image,  content with SVG text or SVG path, but have landed on either text content or `:after`.

The buttons are bigger, vertically, then some of the other elements in same beholder. It all should align middle vertically.

When using text I had to set `line-height: 0` to make it align vertically. Is this OK? Which one of the two is better if any?

I had to add `padding-top: 2px` to get it to align. Could this become an issue across browsers?

I like the content version best as it makes for less *extra* classes, complexity and bloatnes. For now I need +/-, but likely would need other ones holding for example `×`, `/`, *single letters* etc. One other reason I abandoned the background and SVG.

Simple example:

```css
body {
  background: #888;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #555;
  color: #ddd;
  font: bold 14px arial;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.button_1 {
  font: bold 32px arial;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_2:after {
  font: bold 32px arial;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.button_2_minus:after {
  content: '\2212';
}

.button_2_plus:after {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="button_1">&minus;</button>
        <input type="text" />
        <button class="button_1">+</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        1. Text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="button_2 button_2_minus">&nbsp;</button>
        <input type="text" />
        <button class="button_2 button_2_plus">&nbsp;</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        2. :after
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a table? Tables may or may not scale properly on different devices. You could do a similar layout with **div** elements using **flex** display type. Flex allows you to write sophisticated alignment for the elements.

Comment: You should reduce the font-size of the buttons and give them less height & width. The center alignment will still work properly.

Comment: @Janne: OK. I'll keep that in mind. For this project it is a table. There is 10 data columns and this column with +/- is one in middle and one at last column.

Comment: @SrishtiGupta: The point of the Q is the size of the font and buttons and the alignment with these and other elements.